# Is it possible to reverse engineer the NodeMCU frightanic build specs using the commit number?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I am just starting out with IoT and I purchased a 2-pack of ESP8266's v2's (CP1201 DOIT.AM).  Both came with an old version of a [frightanic](https://frightanic.com/) NodeMCU build.  In learning more about NodeMCU/LUA, I realized I needed to flash them to add more features for my project.  In flashing new firmware, I have since learned that baud rates have greatly changed (9600 - 115k) and was curious what else has changed from the original version on the ESP8266 to the new version.

So is it possible to take a build commit number from [frightanic](https://frightanic.com/) and use it to either reverse engineer or lookup the specs of that build so that I better know what I am dealing with for my project?

Original (old) build specs:

> NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com 
>  
>     branch: master 
>     commit: c8037568571edb5c568c2f8231e4f8ce0683b883 
>     SSL: false 
>     modules: cjson,file,gpio,net,node,pwm,tmr,uart,wifi 
>    build    built on: 2016-03-14 02:10 
>    powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 1.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firmware project repository is hosted on GitHub. The whole history there plus the commit ID you showed in the Q leads to

https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/tree/c8037568571edb5c568c2f8231e4f8ce0683b883

- That firmware is close to two years old - that's ancient.
- At that time we didn't even have the documentation in the repository (`/docs` folder is missing).

> So is it possible to take a build commit number from frightanic and use it to either reverse engineer or lookup the specs of that build

The specs is basically what showed in the Q. Given the Git revision and the list of modules you can recreate that firmware any time.